# Return the count of the most frequently occurring string based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large table of data in Excel 2013 similar to the following:

```
A(Include?)  B(Name)       C(Region)

   1        John Doe        North
   0        Jim Stevens     South
   0        Tom Brooks      West
   1        Bob Smith       West
   1        Mike Thomas     North
   0        Steve Adams     East
   1        John Smith      Northwest
```

I need help coming up with an Excel formula that will show me the count of the most frequently occurring **Region** name, but only if the corresponding **Include?** value is equal to 1.

In this example, the formula that I need would output the number 2, because North is the most frequently occurring entry in the **Region** column, while only counting the entries whose **Include?** value is equal to 1.

I've been able to find the most frequently occurring region (without regard for the include column) using the following array function:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MODE(IF(C:C<>"",MATCH(C:C,C:C,0))))
```

I was then able to find the number of times that this value appears in the column using:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,INDEX(C:C,MODE(IF(C:C<>"",MATCH(C:C,C:C,0)))))
```

However, when I try to account for the **Include?** column, I do not get the correct answer. My best guess was:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,C:C,INDEX(C:C,MODE(IF(C:C<>"",MATCH(C:C,C:C,0)))),A:A,1)
```

It appears that this formula is still finding the original **Region**, and simply telling me the number of times that it's occurring in the rows where **Include?** is equal to 1, not recalculating the most frequently occurring region based on this additional limitation.

I'm expecting that the required formula would somehow combine `COUNTIFS` and/or `SUMIFS` and/or some `INDEX+MATCH` combo, but I'd be open to other options.

Comment: We can help you debug/fix something you've already tried, but we're not a free consulting service.

Comment: I've been working on this for days, trying different combinations of COUNTIFS criteria and INDEX(MATCH()) strategies. Not looking for a "free consulting service", just anyone that has either seen this situation before, or might know more than I do.

Comment: Look at the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-991C9ADC-88DC-4AB9-9FBF-04346623D79D), available since Excel 2010. Showing examples of your previous efforts (successful or not) is much more likely to get you the assitance you are looking for.

Comment: @Phil, that's cool.  Show us what you've tried.  The latest example if there are too many.  Your question must include the minimum work you've done to replicate your issue.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my question to show my best guess so far. If anyone can offer any insight, it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: @Jeeped The AGGREGATE function would work, but I don't believe it lets you ignore rows based on cell contents other than error values. Do you know of any similar functions that do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,C:C,INDEX(C:C,MODE(IF(C:C<>"",MATCH(C:C,C:C,0)))))
```

this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula.
tell me if it doesn't work.
I tried this formula in my sample worksheet, and I am getting the expected results.

Comment: are you pressing ***ctrl+shift+enter***  to calculate the formula?

Comment: I did pass ctrl+shift+enter to calculate, and I'm not getting the correct answer.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro so in your example, you are expecting 2 because the count of North with 1 in column A is two. right?

Comment: @Yes.  I verified that it works for multiple test cases even after the data is changed.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro please try this formula and pay attention when copy pasting. it is returning the expected answers for me.

Comment: I think this answer is along the right lines but you need to include the column A condition within the MODE part so that INDEX finds the region which is the most common **within that condition**, i.e. `=COUNTIFS(C2:C99,INDEX(C2:C99,MODE(IF(C2:C99<>"",IF(A2:A99=1,MATCH(C2:C99,C2:C99,0))))),A2:A99,1)` - I think that would give the same result as Jeeped's solution, and although longer it would be quicker over large amounts of data

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX(C:C,MODE(IF(A:A=1, MATCH(C:C,C:C,0))))
```

You were very close.  All you need to do if change your array function to check if column A equals 1 opposed to checking if column C isn't blank and this will work for you.  I tested out some different scenarios.

NOTE: After putting in the formula you have to hit SHIFT + CTRL + ENTER on a PC or COMMAND + ENTER on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Formula:
`=COUNTIFS($A:$A,1,$C:$C,MODE.SNGL(VALUE($C$2:$C$7)))`

This formula counts rows where `Include?` is equal to 1 and `Region` is the mode of values in `Region`.  I'm taking advantage of the fact that the region names all have different first letters.

Note: In the event of a "Tie" in the mode function, it takes the value closest to the top of the sheet.

Comment: Thanks! This is almost exactly what I need, but perhaps I should have specified in my example that all the region names don't have unique first letters. I also have Northwest, Southwest, etc...

Comment: So... your question contains invalid data?  You should list your regions in your question.

Comment: Ok, I made the requested change.

Comment: So you have only North, South, East, West and Northwest?

Comment: I have a total of 30 regions, so I didn't list them all. If possible, I would prefer that the formula did not hard-code the region names, since not all of my regions are applicable each day.

Comment: Your requirement relies on the `MODE` function which can only take a number.  If you could use a region ID# instead that would work.

Comment: Ok, I can translate the region to a region ID. What would be the function in that case?

Comment: I'm still not getting the correct answer here. I tried removing the CODE function as well, since now I'm using numeric ID's.

Comment: Are your ID's stored as text?

Comment: No, stored as numbers.

Comment: Well, it works for me.  I've even tried 20+ permutations.  Do your ID cells have green arrows in the corner?

Comment: No they don't. I think the problem is the same one that I had in my original example. The COUNTIFS function is still only counting the number of Include cells where the Region is equal to the original most-frequent region, not the region that is most frequently occurring among items where Include is equal to 1.

Comment: Try the new formula I posted. And update your question to include the actual ID's you're using.

Comment: Thanks, but still no. If anything that's worse, since my ID's were not stored as text.

Comment: Ha.  That would not have changed anything.  Even if the numbers weren't text adding the `VALUE` function changes nothing.  And... you need to update your question to reflect what you're trying now.

Comment: Well it changed my answer...but I'm not understanding how or why.

Comment: Are you sure the ranges are correct?  I can make the formula more general if that will help, but the `MODE` function does not like blanks or any text in its range.

Comment: That spreadsheet only represents the information I have in different columns. The information itself is not exactly what I'm working with, since it's sensitive data. Also, my spreadsheet is much larger.

Comment: The `MODE` function requires the exact range of numerical values.  If you've included the whole column or any text or blanks it will not work.

Comment: Ah, so there's the problem. I have quite a few blanks in my table. What if we approached the problem differently, where instead of counting the region cells we're counting the "include" cells. Since these are either 0 or 1 and there are no blanks, we may have an easier time. In this case, I would need the count of the 1's in this column where the Region equals the most frequently occurring Region amongst the 1's only.

Comment: We still need the `MODE` function to grab the most frequent value from the Regions.

Comment: Ok, so what if I put 0's in all the empty cells. Can we have MODE exclude 0 from it's counting?

Answer (score 0):

Standard (*non-array*) formula to retrieve the maximum number of occurrences of duplicates in columns C (e.g. *North, South, West, etc.*) where column A is *1*.

```
=MAX(INDEX((A2:A99=1)*COUNTIFS(A2:A99, 1, C2:C99, C2:C99), , ))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is definitely not calculating the value I'm looking for.

Comment: This doesn't work.  It just gives the count of the most common value in column C.  I can change all of the values in Column A and nothing changes.

Comment: My apologies - I pasted the wrong formula from the sample worksheet.

Comment: This works, but will be geometrically slower the more rows it covers.  Anything more than 200 or so rows will cause a big slowdown every recalc.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro - Please define *'big slowdown*'. I've just timed it on 5000 rows and the calculation time was 0.363 seconds (5 year old i5 laptop/32-bit Excel 2010)

Comment: I posted a comment on AHC's answer - I think that the MODE approach will be quicker over 5000 rows if you set that up correctly, it is in my tests, but this works for me - even without the first condition - I think you can use just: `=MAX(INDEX(COUNTIFS(A2:A99, 1, C2:C99, C2:C99),0))`