# Return most common value in a list based on criterion

Tags: excel, criteria, mode

I found a similar question here ([Return the count of the most frequently occurring string based on multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132616/return-the-count-of-the-most-frequently-occurring-string-based-on-multiple-crite)) but did not see a satisfactory answer. Please help if you can!

I have a list of Manufacturers and their products:

**Manf.......Product..........Metric**
Adobe......Photoshop.....User
Adobe......Acrobat.........User
Microsoft..Office............Device
Microsoft..Access.........Device
Microsoft..MSDN..........MSDN Named User

In another table I have a list of unique Manufacturer names, and I need to be able to say what the most common (and then second most common, hopefully) metric per manufacturer is, as below.

**Manf.........Most Common Metric**
Adobe.......User
Microsoft...Device

I would prefer not to have a VBA solution in this case, but will use if necessary. I have seem some INDEX MATCH attempts but nothing is working quite right yet. Thank you!

**EDIT:** I thought of another way to search for answers and found this, which worked! http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/formula-to-return-most-common-value/06383764-3c7d-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?auth=1

Anyone know how to modify it to find the second and third most common values?

Comment: Just do countif on each criteria than sort? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You can modify the function in the referenced post by using the `LARGE` function in place of the `MAX` function

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirement, a PivotTable should show you what you want:

[image: SO32896096 example]

This is in Tabular form without Totals and without Subtotals but with 'Metric' sorted Descending by Count of Metric. Repeat items labels is not checked as this may help with identifying where 'most common' starts for each `Manf`.